# open geotiff obtained from NetCDF in python - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I created a geotiff from a netCDF file through the following code, but when I try to access the resulting file in python again, this gives me the following error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'  and I do not understand the reason for such! However, the file opens correctly in other software, such as QGIS. Can you help me?

```
ncdf=netCDF4.Dataset(file,'r')

lat=ncdf.variables["LAT"][:]
lon=ncdf.variables["LON"][:]
var =ncdf.variables["VAR"][:]

(code to convert LAT and LON in X and Y UTM coordinates)

 X=...
 Y=...

 nx=len(X)
 a=numpy.shape(var)
 ny=a[1]

 xres=30
 yres=30

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [X.min(), Y.min(), X.max(), Y.max()]

geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)

 Wkt="""PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N",
            GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
            UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
            UNIT["metre",1,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
            PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
            PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
            PARAMETER["central_meridian",-9],
            PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
            PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
            PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","32629"],
            AXIS["Easting",EAST],
            AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]"""


  dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('./B1_CATM.tif', ny, nx, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
  dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(refAerosol) 

  dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform) 

  srs = osr.SpatialReference()            
  srs.ImportFromWkt(Wkt)
  srs.ImportFromEPSG(32629)

  dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())


  # AND IN OTHER SCRIPT OPEN THIS GEOTIFF File:

  B=gdal.Open('directoryfile.tif')
  Band=B.GetRasterBand(1)

 # the following error message appears: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
 'GetRasterBand'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get more information about why GDAL can't open your file if you put `import gdal; gdal.UseExceptions()` at the top. If you don't do this, `gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create()` will return None with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'` is Python's way of saying it all went wrong. The problem is that the first line returns `None` (or null to the rest of us non-python types), and then you tried to use that value in the second line.

```
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('./B1_CATM.tif', ny, nx, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(refAerosol)
```

So you need to work out why GDAL is not reading in your tif file. It might be the name or location is wrong, or the type is wrong or that `nx` & `ny` are wrong.

In general, it is good practice to check the datastore returned by GDAL to make sure nothing went wrong before you attempt to use it.

Comment: I found this answer useful because it was indeed my location